# excel date difference function fetches incorrect result

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

> I am calculating date difference but getting incorrect result sample
> screenshot is attached.

An example is

> '=DATEDIF("31-12-2007","01-01-2008","md")'

It should fetch 1 day but its fetching 114 days.

> 3rd column formula " =DATEDIF($A2,$B2,C$1)"
>
> 4th column formula " =DATEDIF($A2,$B2,D$1)"
>
> 5th column formula " =DATEDIF($A2,$B2,E$1)"
>
> 6th column formula " =DATEDIF($A2,$B2,F$1)"
>
> 7th column formula " =DATEDIF($A2,$B2,G$1)"
>
> 8th column formula " =DATEDIF($A2,$B2,H$1)"
>
> plz help how to resolve this.

Comment: See the known issues section here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your date format. Probably excel doesn't see them as dates.

Comment: I checked this by adding 1 to start date and i got next date
"=A3+1"
A3 had value "01-01-2021"
result I got was "02-01-2021"
so I think date format is not a problem.